# How to wrap a message into app component in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

This question could be silly but I know how to do that on react but not in angular.
If I have a component with styles and I would like to call that component to introduce by default on the element a message, how can I allocate that message on this component (not through Input param)

e.g.

- main component:

```html
<app-mycomp>This is my message toallocate</app-mycomp>
```

- on app-mycomp could be:

```html
<ng-content>
  <mat-icon fontIcon="icon"></mat-icon>
  <mat-label>{{messageToAllocate}}</mat-label>
</ng-content>
```

how I could understand myself. On react I know there is on a prop an input called children and I can call that children variable to put on the jsx but no idea how to do that on Angular. But again, I don't want to do it as an input because I don't want to put a param on the element.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your component template needs to look like this:

```
<mat-icon fontIcon="icon"></mat-icon>   
<mat-label><ng-content></ng-content></mat-label>
```

The `ng-content` element serves as a placeholder (or *slot*) into which content defined in the outer component can be *projected*.

See [docs](https://angular.io/guide/content-projection) on *content projection*.

Comment: thank you so much, that was precisely that I was looking for.